# How many kinds of built-in VisualState are there in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp

For me, the known VisualStates are:

- Pressed
- Focused
- UnFocused
- PointerOver

but I want to know all the built-in VisualStates, and I have searched for a long time and still can't find the relevant information, does anyone know where I can find such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many kinds of built-in VisualState are there in UWP?

It's different with Xamarin Visual State  Manager defines one visual state group named "CommonStates" with the following visual states:
"Normal"
"Disabled"
"Focused"
"Selected".

In UWP platform, it does not contain such default state. it is useful because such a VisualState will use **whatever values are present** in the [default template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate?view=winrt-22000#default-state).  Each attribute **should specify the state's x:Name attribute**, which is the stateName value a control consumer would pass in a [GoToState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate?view=winrt-22000#windows-ui-xaml-visualstatemanager-gotostate(windows-ui-xaml-controls-control-system-string-system-boolean)) call to use that visual state. For more detail please refer to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate?view=winrt-22000).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and i'm really sorry for the late, for some reason I didn't have time until now.
In fact, what I mean by built-in visual state is that the framework will automatically call GoToState to jump to a certain state when the conditions are met, rather than requiring an explicit call to GoToState in the code behind.

Comment: If you were making custom control that inherit exist control such as custom button, you can edit the  built-in visual state directly such as `Pressed` `PointerOver`, but if you are making new control, you need to spcific each visual state and call them in the code behind.

Comment: I understand, I'm talking about the built-in visual states. Does the built-in visual state depend on the default template of the control?

Comment: There is not  built-in visual state, you need declar each visual state base on your design.

Comment: There may be no built-in visual state for custom controls, but there should be for built-in controls like "Button", like "PointerOver", "Disabled", "Pressed", etc. For the "Pressed" visual state, it looks like it should be jumped using GoToState in the "ButtonBase" code-behind. Thanks again for your reply!